# What is the code created by the BizTalk WCF Service Publishing Wizard?

Tags: wcf, biztalk, biztalk-2010, esb-toolkit-2.0, biztalk-schemas

We have exposed a BizTalk Schema as a WCF service for a third party vendor so that they can push messages onto our ESB.  The WCF service has a single function which accepts and returns messages of that schema type.  The issue is that if a response is not made in a timely manner or another message e.g. an error is generated by the ESB the third party app fails/crashes.

It doesn't really matter what is in the message as long as it is in the correct format and the data in the returned message is not used by the vendor or ourselves.  The vendor also supplies its own WCF service which we can use to pass back messages should we wish to do so.  I would like to modify the existing WCF service or manually create an new one which immediately returns a response but also passes the message onto the ESB for further processing.

I have created an interface from the WSDL using svcutil but cannot find any code examples of how manually create a WCF service to expose a BizTalk schema. All examples point to the wizard.

What is the code that the wizard creates? Is there an example? Thank you.

**EDIT 23/08/2013**

So it would appear that changing a wcf service created by the wizard is not an option nor is creating a new service manually.  I have tried creating an orchestration which consumes the service and sends a response then binding that to the same receive port which works if the itinerary works but doesn't run if there is an error.  Plus it only runs after the itinerary is complete which is no good.  I need an immediate response.

Answer (score 2):

You can change a wcf service created by the wizard, but it is generally better to use the Wizard to re-publish it using the below from the command line.

```
BtsWcfServicePublishingWizard -WcfServiceDescription=C:\..\WcfServiceDescription.xml
```

The WcfServiceDescription.xml will be under under the folder where you published the web service in \App_Data\Temp\ e.g. C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\BizTalkWcfService\App_Data\Temp\WcfServiceDescription.xml

Keeping a copy of this xml file in your source control is a good idea.  Running the wizard against the one under the web service is not a good idea as it deletes and re-creates everything in the folder and so you might manage to corrupt it, so copy it out first and run against the copy.